# how to integrate between MONGODB & SOLR, using MONGO-CONNECTOR

Tags: mongodb, solr

I am very new to mongodb and solr can any one help me to  integrate between MONGODB & SOLR,  using MONGO-CONNECTOR

1.like this i was started my mongod with replSet mod

```
mongod --dbpath=/home/local/ASSYST-COC/so/mongo  --replSet myrep --auth
```

2.mongo started

```
mongo -u root -p root --authenticationDatabase admin
```

3.IN mongo already i have dbs with some collections
4.started solr

```
java -jar start.jar(version 4.7)
```

5.next mongoconnector started

```
 sudo python /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo-connector/mongo_connector.py -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:8983/solr  -o /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo-connector/config.txt -a root -p root -n smmc-dart.testcase  -d /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo-connector/doc_managers/solr_doc_manager.py
```

After mongo connector started in  terminal it showing like.

```
2014-04-07 16:11:19,865 - INFO - Beginning Mongo Connector
2014-04-07 16:11:21,335 - INFO - Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
2014-04-07 16:11:21,469 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/? commit=true' (post) with body 'u'<commit ' in 0.159 seconds.
2014-04-07 16:11:21,475 - INFO - MongoConnector: Empty oplog progress file.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 530, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo-connector/mongo_connector.py", line 204, in run
repl_set = prim_admin.command("replSetGetStatus")['set']
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 396, in command
msg, allowable_errors)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 147, in _check_command_response
raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code)
```

OperationFailure: command SON([('replSetGetStatus', 1)]) failed: unauthorized

```
2014-04-07 16:11:22,489 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/?  commit=true' (post) with body 'u'<commit ' in 0.018 seconds.
```

Nothing is updating in Solr.

6.I was checked in solr brower

Is anything i need to  do more  please share to me

Comment: What was wrong with the [documentation](https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector) or do you actually have a specific problem that you are not actually asking in your question?

Comment: @Neil Lunn I was updated my question  can please check

Comment: Sure, better detail. But you are on the wrong site. Try [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/) or [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). StackExchange is specifically for programming related questions. This question is about configuring services.

Comment: @Neil Lunn I need to Login serverfault.com. again i need to post this question in that form

Comment: They are all stack exchange sites as is StackOverflow. You use the same login details. And you will even get 100 rep automatically because you already have a stackoverflow account. Bonus :)

Comment: @Neil Lunn thank u  logined with same user name and password how to see current details in that  sites

Comment: @Neil Lunn posted same question in to  this form serverfault.com